# Query mysql when reach row then stop? show the queue number

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am doing a script want to calculate how many row record before an user record when `t1.status` is `1`.

My table is `t1`, and the data as below:

```
+------+---------+------------+----------+----------+
| ID   | name    | desc       | status   | time     |
+------+---------+------------+----------+----------+
| 1    | ABB     |            | 1        | 0325     |
| 2    | CCD     |            | 1        | 0236     |
| 3    | EEF     |            | 1        | 0325     |
| 4    | GGG     |            | 1        | 0000     |
| 5    | HIJ     |            | 2        | 1234     |
| 6    | KKK     |            | 1        | 5151     |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I was thinking about the query is something like `(query row where status = 1 AND stop when reach $userid)`

I would like to output to show user (Let's say username is `GGG`) as:
`$userid = 'GGG';`

then my output will be

```
<table><tr><td>Queue: GGG You came in 4 place, in front of you still got 3 person in queue, please be patient</td></tr></table>
```

How to I do the right query to get the number `4` and `3` ?

Thank you.

Comment: How would you calculate `3` manually to begin with? 3 people with _lower `ID`_ and status 1?

Comment: Please show your code first.

Comment: No, the `id` is Auto increment ID only, since before `GGG` have 3 record is `status = 1`, so I would like to output to `GGG`, in front of it have `3` record, and `GGG` is fourth record, something like that.

Comment: Your select should be based on the time of login. you have `time` on your field. For example when a user login, you insert or update the time and accordingly you can calculate who is first in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this hope it helps :-

SELECT count(*) as `COUNT` FROM `t1` WHERE id < (SELECT id FROM `t1` WHERE `userid` = $userid)